# How to display record number for all database

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to loop (in php) thought database to display records for each table.

```
$retrun.=TableName." ".$RecordNumber
```

I know how to count for one specific table but I don't know how to loop.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there a simple solution for that

```
SELECT table_name, table_rows
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<your db>'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an even simpler solution.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_database
WHERE (whatever)
```